# Comparing values in one dictionary with values from another dictionary in Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'Canada' : 2.5, 'UK' : 3.7, 'USA' : 9.0}
dict2 = {'a' : 7, 'b' : 2}
```

I want to be able to loop through the **values** in `dict1` using the values in `dict2` to determine which elements are larger. The output should be:

```
a is larger than Canada.
a is larger than UK.
```

(as 7 is obviously greater than 2.5 and 3.7). I hope that makes sense!

So far, I have written:

```
for k, v in dict2.items():
    for i, j in dict2:
        print (k, " is larger than ", i)
```

I receive this error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What if the value for b was 4... What would be displayed then?

Comment: You mean `b`?..

Comment: `a is larger than Canada. a is larger than UK. b is larger than Canada. b is larger than UK.`

Comment: `for i, j in dictx.items():`  to fix the ValueError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea. Iterate the items in both dicts and compare

```
>>> dict1 = {'Canada' : 2.5, 'UK' : 3.7, 'USA' : 9.0}
>>> dict2 = {'a' : 7, 'b' : 2}
>>> 
>>> 
>>> for kd2, vd2 in dict2.items():
...     for kd1, vd1 in dict1.items():
...         if vd2 > vd1:
...             print(kd2, "is larger than", kd1)
... 
a is larger than Canada
a is larger than UK
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is just due to the fact that you are missing the `.items()` in iterating over `dict2`.  You're just iterating over keys, so it doesn't know how to handle the `i, j`.